# Setting variables before command in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Whats the difference between:

```sh
GIT_TRACE=1 git push
```

and

```sh
GIT_TRACE=1; git push
```

The same do not behave the same, since the first really outputs tracing info while executing `git push` since it obviously checks if such variable is set (environment?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> GIT_TRACE=1 git push
> ```

`GIT_TRACE=1` is added to the environment of the `git push` command. The variable assignment is only in effect for that command. It doesn't affect any subsequent commands.

> ```
> GIT_TRACE=1; git push
> ```

A **shell variable** named `GIT_TRACE` is set to `1`. Shell variables are distinct from **environment variables**. Child processes only see environment variables. They don't see shell variables. It's a subtle distinction. And because of it, `git push` doesn't see the setting and it has no effect.

Also, unlike above the variable continues to be set for the duration of the script.

To make the setting visible you need to **export** it, promoting the shell variable to an environment variable.

```
export GIT_TRACE=1; git push
```

If you don't want the variable to affect any other commands, you could then run both commands in a subshell. Variable assignments in a subshell are lost when the subshell ends.

```
(export GIT_TRACE=1; git push)
```

Of course, there's no reason you would do this since `GIT_TRACE=1 git push` does exactly the same thing but better (it doesn't fork a subshell).